# How to create a wrapper component / directive?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have some markup I would like to cover with a simple wrapper. In this case, the idea is to wrap two `<input>` elements within some markup, so that this markup:

```html
<div class="group-class">
  <div class="first-class">
    <input id="first">
  </div>
  <div class="second-class">
    <input id="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

would be marked up like this instead:

```html
<my-wrapper>
  <input id="first">
  <input id="second">
</my-wrapper>
```

I initially thought of a component, but that would create a shadowDOM, and thus would not behave the same way as if `<my-wrapper>` didn't exist. `<my-wrapper>` tag should replace itself with the content of the first example, so that the DOM rendered is the same. I believe I saw some `replace` option for an angular-directive, but I am very unsure how to do this.

Comment: Check this question and answer by Günter: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156950/repeat-over-elements-provided-as-content) He wants to do something similar but repeats the provided content instead. Maybe you get an idea?

Comment: Thanks. I already checked it out, but is quite complicated. I don't currently understand well enough how `<content>` works, and that is why I am unsure if I can at all base this solution on using a component. I need to understand Angular better, but I think Günther's solution could be used.